# CSOM CamlQuery is returning data I don't believe it should

Tags: 2013, development, csom

I have the following code to retrieve orders from an order list that have a status of `Approved`:

```
private static ListItemCollection LoadListItemCollection()
{
    using (var ctx = new ClientContext("http://sharepoint/resources"))
    {
        var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Resource Orders");

        var query = new CamlQuery
                        {
                            ViewXml =
                                @"<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=""Status""></FieldRef><Value Type=""Text"">Approved</Value></Eq></Where>"
                        };

        var collListItem = list.GetItems(query);

        ctx.Load(
            collListItem,
            items =>
            items.Include(
                item => item.Id,
                item => item.DisplayName,
                item => item.HasUniqueRoleAssignments,
                item => item["Persona"],
                item => item["Quantity_x0020_Ordered"],
                item => item["Resource_x0020_Name"],
                item => item["Title"],
                item => item["Customer_x0020_E_x002d_mail"],
                item => item["Customer_x0020_Phone_x0020_Numbe"],
                item => item["Customer_x0020_Street"],
                item => item["Customer_x0020_Suburb"],
                item => item["Customer_x0020_Postcode"],
                item => item["Organization"],
                item => item["Created"]));

        ctx.ExecuteQuery();

        return collListItem;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately it's returning every item in the list and appears to be ignoring my where clause. I know I could always remove these from the collection once they're there, but how do I prevent them from being loaded in the first place?

Although I believe the problem is my `CamlQuery` here's the full class for the code above, in case it's relevant:

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

/// <summary>
/// Class for loading orders from SharePoint and interacting with them
/// </summary>
public static class Orders
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Backing field for storing the latest orders that have been retrieved from SharePoint
    /// </summary>
    private static ListItemCollection ordersCache;

    /// <summary>
    /// Property for retrieving cached orders, will fetch and set if none are currently present.
    /// </summary>
    public static ListItemCollection CachedOrders => ordersCache ?? (ordersCache = LoadListItemCollection());

    /// <summary>
    /// Property to retrieve the latest orders and cache for future reference.
    /// </summary>
    public static ListItemCollection LatestOrders => ordersCache = LoadListItemCollection();

    /// <summary>
    /// Loads orders from SharePoint using CAML
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// The <see cref="ListItemCollection"/>.
    /// </returns>
    private static ListItemCollection LoadListItemCollection()
    {
        using (var ctx = new ClientContext("http://sharepoint/resources"))
        {
            var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Resource Orders");

            var query = new CamlQuery
                            {
                                ViewXml =
                                    @"<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=""Status""></FieldRef><Value Type=""Text"">Approved</Value></Eq></Where>"
                            };

            var collListItem = list.GetItems(query);

            ctx.Load(
                collListItem,
                items =>
                items.Include(
                    item => item.Id,
                    item => item.DisplayName,
                    item => item.HasUniqueRoleAssignments,
                    item => item["Persona"],
                    item => item["Quantity_x0020_Ordered"],
                    item => item["Resource_x0020_Name"],
                    item => item["Title"],
                    item => item["Customer_x0020_E_x002d_mail"],
                    item => item["Customer_x0020_Phone_x0020_Numbe"],
                    item => item["Customer_x0020_Street"],
                    item => item["Customer_x0020_Suburb"],
                    item => item["Customer_x0020_Postcode"],
                    item => item["Organization"],
                    item => item["Created"]));

            ctx.ExecuteQuery();

            return collListItem;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set your CAML Query like this:

```
ViewXml = @"<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=""Status""></FieldRef><Value Type=""Text"">Approved</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>"
```

Comment: This works, thank-you. Could you explain why? Even just a good CAML resource would be great, MSDN hasn't helped me much in understanding its nuances.

Comment: Unlike Server Object Model, In CSOM the `<View>` is required element in querying. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/738008/Programming-Efficiently-with-the-SharePoint-Client . I will try to provide even better reference for it.

Comment: Thank-you, great insights already. Will dig deeper on it!